# Mysql stored procedure wrong result set if a cursor to information_schema.tables is opened

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which uses data from `information_schema` database and does some logic on other tables based on that. However the problem appears to be that if a `CURSOR` is opened to  `information_schema`.`tables` table then any following `SELECT` statement (say to table `tbl2`) return `NULL` values for all columns in that other table.

`tbl2` data:

```
intcol |  longtextcol                    | blobcol 
----------------------------------------------------------------
4      |  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 44  | qwerqwerqwerqw
6      |  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 55  | asdfadsfasdfasdfasdfs
7      |  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 66  | qwerqwer
44     |  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 99  | qwerqwerqwer
55     |  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 100 | qwerqwerwerqwer
60     |  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 110 | rwwwqfqwfq
66     |  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 120 | wehewdbssdfb
77     |  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 130 | asvasdffasdf
99     |  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 140 | asdfasdvadsbasgfgdfsa
```

Stored procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test.foo;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test.foo()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE tblCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`tables` ;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    OPEN tblCursor;
    SELECT * from `test`.`tbl2`; -- returns wrong result set
END$$
DELIMITER ;
CALL test.foo();
```

Result:

```
intcol |  longtextcol | blobcol 
-------------------------------
[NULL] |  [NULL]      | [NULL] 
[NULL] |  [NULL]      | [NULL] 
[NULL] |  [NULL]      | [NULL] 
[NULL] |  [NULL]      | [NULL] 
[NULL] |  [NULL]      | [NULL] 
[NULL] |  [NULL]      | [NULL] 
[NULL] |  [NULL]      | [NULL] 
[NULL] |  [NULL]      | [NULL] 
[NULL] |  [NULL]      | [NULL]
```

The strange part is that if the `CURSOR` is declared to any other table (*not* `information_schema`.`columns` or `information_schema`.`tables`) then the following `SELECT` to `tbl1` returns *correct* results. Can anyone could please explain why this is happening and how to access data in `tbl2`?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Using: `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for osx10.13 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

The *correct* result set is also returned if `SELECT * from test.tbl2;` is placed before opening the cursor. e.g.:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test.foo;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test.foo()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE tblCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`columns`;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    SELECT * from `test`.`tbl2`; -- returns correct result set
    OPEN tblCursor;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
CALL test.foo();
```

Comment: I don't believe cursor has anything to do with it - I cannot reproduce your issue , what db are you USEing and what do you get if you run  SELECT * from `test`.`tbl2`; from the db in USE, and do check other dbs to see if there are any others where tbl2 exists.

Comment: @P.Salmon, the reason I suspect it to be something around `CURSOR` is because if I do the `SELECT` _before_ I open the `CURSOR` then it returns correct results. e.g.
...
SELECT * from `test`.`tbl2`; -- returns correct result set
OPEN tblCursor;
...
Secondly, as mentioned before, if the cursor is defined for any other table except it also works correctly. 
Using: `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for osx10.13 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`
Also checked, not `tbl1` nor `tbl2` tables exists in any other databases.
It could be something very obvious/silly but just cant figure it out.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error either on my box or https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8FGCRVGPdmvvzjvsUAuchy/0. - I doubt if anyone can help given the information provided.

Comment: @P.Salmon, thanks for the effort, I appreciate it. It was actually helpful in the sense that now I know that there is some weird behaviour within my db. I have tested on other databases we have access (remote) to and it works just fine as it does on yours. As soon as I point the client to my local db I get this weird issue. Also tried it running directly it directly in terminal to eliminate any issues with db client used but still get the same weird behaviour even in the terminal. So there must be something with my local mysql server/databases.